# Custom partitioner in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a Cassandra table with three columns devid, epoch, dimension. Now for analytics purposes over Spark, I wanted to have all data of a specific devid to go to the same node irrespective of dimension and epoch so that there is good data locality and for analytics of a single devid, I can avoid network data shuffling in Spark.

However the amount of data for each devid will be too huge to be efficient in a single partition. Hence I cannot define a primary key like (devid, dimension, epoch). So I need to go for a key like ((devid, dimension), epoch) which will be manageable. However this will start putting data of a single devid on multiple nodes (and then Spark will require to do data shuffling over network for analytics over a single devid).

Can I create a custom parititioner which will consider devid and ignore the dimension in the key ((devid, dimension), epoch) for generating the paritition token? Is it advisable to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you intend to have multiple partitions but force them to still reside on the same node?... unless your replication factor is 1, you'll still be putting data on multiple nodes anyway, I'm not sure why you want to do this?

Have you looked at the Spark cassandra connector, or other similar things?

This may also be useful:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html

Comment: I donot require all partitions to reside on the same node. I want all partitions having same 'devid' to reside on the same node. I have added some more context by editing the question. Can you please relook at it? Thanks.